# Explicitly remove object from list within a python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For a dungeon crawler, I have a loot dictionary and a pack dictionary. Each contain lists.
I have successfully appended random objects (which are 'found'). But, now I need to randomly remove objects (which are 'stolen'). (I will also need to explicitly remove objects for selling/substitution.)
The items in the pack lists are each instances of a Weapon or other class type (each with the attribute '.item_type') which correspond to the keys.
I have included some of the statements I have tried over the past few days, including del and pop, which are commented out.
In particular, pop gives errors like 'TypeError: 'LeatherBoots' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'

Other similar posts address dictionaries within lists, but not lists within dictionaries.

```
import ...



pack = {
    'Weapons': [],
    'Healing Potions': [],
    'Armor': [],
    'Shields': [],
    'Boots': [],
    'Cloaks': [],
    'Rings of Regeneration': [],
    'Rings of Protection': [],
    'Town Portal Implements': []
}
loot_dict = {
    'Weapons': [short_sword, short_axe, quantum_sword, broad_sword],
    'Healing Potions': [minor_healing_potion, major_healing_potion, super_healing_potion],
    'Armor': [leather_armor],
    'Shields': [buckler],
    'Boots': [leather_boots],
    'Cloaks': [canvas_cloak],
    'Rings of Regeneration': [ring_of_regeneration],
    'Rings of Protection': [ring_of_protection],
    'Town Portal Implements': [scroll_of_town_portal]
}
value, key = random.choice(list(loot_dict.items()))
rndm_item = random.choice(loot_dict[value])
(pack[rndm_item.item_type]).append(rndm_item)
#(pack[rndm_item.item_type]).pop(rndm_item)
#del value
#pack.pop(random.choice(list(pack.values())))
print(rndm_item)
print(rndm_item.item_type)
print(pack)
```

Comment: `list.pop()` takes an *index* as a parameter (or you can omit it, to remove the first item in the list).  Removing a specific item by passing the item itself would be done via `list.remove()` or `list.discard()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```py
# Get types of items which player have
available = []
for i in pack.keys():
    if len(pack[i]) > 0:
        available.append(i)
t = random.choice(available)   # Get an item type you want to "steal" (i.e. Weapon, Armor, etc.)
if len(available) > 0:
    if len(pack[t]) > 0:  # If the player has an item of type "t",
        pack[t].pop(random.randint(0, len(pack[t]) - 1)) # remove it
else:
 # nothing to steal
```

It'll remove random item from `pack`.

The `list.pop` doesn't take a **value** as argument, rather than an **index**. You tried to put a value, so nothing worked.

```py
['a', # index: 0; value: 'a'
 'b', # index: 1, value: 'b',
 'c'  # index: 2, value: 'c']
```

When you put a list's item into a variable, while using `del variable`, you actually delete the variable **itself**, not an item.

Comment: Just as a heads up, you can press `ctrl+k` to format a block of text as code

Comment: This randomly chooses a type and then randomly chooses an item of that type - which means that the canvas cloak is more likely to be stolen than the broad sword.

Comment: Better to add an `(item_type, item_index)` tuple to available and then delete _that_ item.  (The OP might want to add some items multiple times if they are particularly easy/attractive to steal.)

Comment: Thank you...this partially works. Yet, I am randomly getting pop index out of range errors.. ```pack[t].pop(random.randint(0, len(pack[t]))) # remove it``` is the culprit.

Comment: I changed ```pack[t].pop(random.randint(0, len(pack[t])))``` to ```pack[t].pop(random.randint(0, len(pack[t])-1))```. This seems to remove the out of range errors. I am guessing 'len' counts from 1, whereas the random range indexes from 0...I can upvote and select your answer if you would like to update your code to help others! Thank you very much!

Comment: I fixed it! Sorry for inattention!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete element from list with random index:

```
key = random.choice(list(loot_dict.keys()))
rndm_item_index = random.randrange(len(loot_dict[key]))
rndm_item = loot_dict[key][rndm_item_index]
pack[rndm_item.item_type].append(rndm_item)
del loot_dict[key][rndm_item_index]
```

Also you should check that `loot_dict` and `loot_dict[key]` both a not empty.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is helpful, but I am trying to delete from the pack dictionary...I get index out of range errors with your code when I do ```del pack[key][rndm_item_index]``` since the indexes don't line up. The loot_dict will always remain unchanged, unless I add new custom instances..

Comment: Yes it is. In `pack[key]` indexes is different from indexes in `loot_dict[key]` and you need to find a new index for deletion. There is a multiple ways to do in this situation. You can store all items in one long list, and add property `location` to every item (no deletion, no problem), or you can use id of objects (`id(rndm_item)`) to trace them in different lists, or you can use `dict` like structure with item object as key and count as value (`default_dict` for ex.).